# Unable to run Jmeter behind proxy

Tags: windows, proxy, jmeter

My test objective is to monitor performance of native mobile app . For that I choose Jmeter v5.2.1 . 
I have downloaded jmeter on my laptop . I make sure ApacheJMeterTempararyRootCA.crt is on my prosurface .(where I have downloaded native mobile app) .

I have configured prosurface device to same wifi connection as my laptop where jmeter runs . Amended proxy address and given port that is given in jmeter running in my laptop .

I have started running Jmeter and mobile app .But nothing is getting recorded in HTTP(s) Test Script Recorder. And internet is not working in prosurface when I change the proxy .

I have changed proxy in option>internet options >connections>LAN settings>checked 'Use a proxy server for your LAN' and entered IP address and port .

Can someone please suggest what need to be done .

Most of Jmeter articles are on Android and iOS .Can some one suggest me article on for windows .

Answer (score 0):

You need to install JMeter's self-signed certificate (`ApacheJMeterTempararyRootCA.crt`) into [Trusted Root Certification Authorities Certificate Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/trusted-root-certification-authorities-certificate-store)

[image]

You might also need to explicitly set system-wide proxy to use JMeter via [netsh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-contexts)

[image]

just replace `localhost` with the hostname or ip address of the machine where JMeter is running at. If you have JMeter on the tablet - you might need to install a special [loopback network adapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/cc708322(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

More information: [How to Run Performance Tests of Desktop Applications Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-desktop-applications-using-jmeter/)